# The databinding of a usercontrol doesn't update the source model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to implement a custom textbox which has a placeholder text. The content of the 'FirstName' property of my model appears in the textbox, as intended. The problem I'm having is when I change the text of the textbox, it isn't updated back in the source model. Why is that?

I've tried setting the binding mode to "TwoWay", but it doesn't change anything. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**: Silly me! As it turns out, I had to put Mode="TwoWay" on both bindings, not just the usercontrol's. I'll mark as answered as soon as possible.

Model.cs

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<grid>
    <ui:prettyTextbox Text="{Binding FirstName}" PlaceholderText="#Enter your name">
</grid>
```

PrettyTextbox.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Name="prettyTextbox">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PlaceholderText, ElementName=prettyTextbox}"
                       Visibility="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=prettyTextbox, Converter={StaticResource StringLengthToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=prettyTextbox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

PrettyTextbox.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PrettyTextbox : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceholderTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceholderText", typeof (string),
                                        typeof(PrettyTextbox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string PlaceholderText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderTextProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PlaceholderTextProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string),
                                    typeof(PrettyTextbox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public PrettyTextbox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to make the text property bind two way by default, so you need to change this part:

```
<ui:prettyTextbox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

or change FrameworkPropertyMetadata of the text property to:

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
{
    DefaultValue = null,
    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
}
```